# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" when its correctly formatted and working on other migration table

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm having trouble with this error because I have already followed the other solution but it's still showing to me. Even tho on other migration seems working on. Here's my code

```
Schema::create('student', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
        $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This migration file is last and my IDs on courses and users are `$table->id()` by default and like I said this code is working on my other migration files.

Comment: Can You Try This ?

$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

Might Get Work

Comment: I already tried that and its not working because the id on courses and users are big integer

Comment: @vivekvaghela i tried your edited code but sadly its still not working

Comment: courses Table Have Any Primary Key ?

Comment: @vivekvaghela im using the default of laravel $table->id();

Comment: can yiu share the order of migrations file ?

Comment: do you have a foreign relation from student? maybe you got it wrong instead of student (without s)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes sense. But it all works out when I change the table name of the student into students. This is so weird on my side because that is not showing on the error. Anyway, If someone came up with the same problem as I just try changing the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's convention is plural table names by default. It makes sense because you are probably  storing multiple data's in the table.

You can add this in your model and get away with your issue.

```
protected $table = 'singular';
```

Here's a good discussion about your problem.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-table-names-are-plural-by-default?page=1